# SugarCRM Get Last Email Date and Search on it

Tags: php, sugarcrm

So I have been working with SugarCRM pretty extensively lately and I need to be able to display the last date a contact was emailed as well search based on how long ago a contact was emailed.

I can easily create a logic hook to get the last email date but I cannot search based on the value of that.

So I looked in SearchFields.php and found the following code which obviously gets the email of the contact.

```
'email' => 
  array (
    'query_type' => 'default',
    'operator' => 'subquery',
    'subquery' => 'SELECT eabr.bean_id FROM email_addr_bean_rel eabr JOIN email_addresses ea ON (ea.id = eabr.email_address_id) WHERE eabr.deleted=0 AND ea.email_address LIKE',
    'db_field' => 
    array (
      0 => 'id',
    ),
  ),
```

Using that data I decided to create a new array with the following code to get the last email date.  Obviously it will need to be sorted or something to get the actual last email date if the contact was emailed multiple times but you get the point.

```
'last_email_c' => 
  array (
    'query_type' => 'default',
    'operator' => 'subquery',
    'subquery' => 'SELECT e.date_sent FROM emails e WHERE e.parent_type = \'Contacts\' AND e.parent_id = \'{0}\'',
    'db_field' => 
    array (
      0 => 'id',
    ),
  ),
```

My issue is, I don't know what to do with this new subquery, I checked in the listviewdefs and the searchdefs and cannot find any reference to either of these custom SearchFields.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

Try this one.  Basically when you use subquery you have to assume that the parameter from the form will be added to the end of the subquery so if you search for blah@blah.com sugar will append to your subquery 'blah@blah.com%'  so LIKE operator is the only way to do this

```
t_email_c' =>  array ( 
'query_type' => 'default',
'operator' => 'subquery',
'subquery' => 'SELECT e.date_sent FROM emails e WHERE e.parent_type = \'Contacts\' AND e.parent_id LIKE ',
'db_field' => 
array (
  0 => 'id',
),
```

Also you should be selecting the id of the parent record so that it could then be matched against the parent record.

Basically in your subquery you should be selecting a contact ID where the last email date is like.

If you can't write query this way you will need to do it by overwriting list.view actions.

Comment: The only issue here is that the records could be out of order, so that may not work.